# Calculating resistance for integrated circuit with logical gates, so that the circuit works properly

Tags: resistors, integrated-circuit, resistance, logic-gates, gate-driving

I have found this task with its solution:

> For the circuit shown below calculate \$R\$ so that the circuit works
> properly. All gates belong to the \$TTL\$ series.
>
> [image]
>
> **Solution:**
> $$\begin{align*}R_{max} &= \frac{V_{CC} -
>  U_{OH_{MIN}}}{\color{red}{N_O} \cdot I_{OH_{MAX}} +
>  \color{blue}{N_{I}} \cdot I_{IH_{MAX}}} = \frac{5 -
>  2.4[V]}{\color{red}{4} \cdot 250 + \color{blue}{3} \cdot 40 [\mu A]} = 2321 \Omega \\ R_{min}&= \frac{V_{CC} - U_{OL_{MAX}}}{I_{OL_{MAX}} -
>  \color{blue}{N_{I}} \cdot I_{IL_{MAX}}} = \frac{5 - 0.4 [V]}{16 -
>  \color{blue}{3} \cdot 1.6 [mA]} = 410  \Omega \end{align*}$$

---

Please ignore the actual current/voltage values, they come from the \$TTL\$ specification.

My questions are:

- how can I determine what's input and what's output?

To my 'sense', \$ABCD\$ are inputs while \$XYZ\$ are outputs.

- Why \$\color{red}{N_{O} = 4}\;\$ (number of outputs) and \$\color{blue}{N_{I} = 3}\;\$ (number of inputs)?

This is the part I am struggling with.

How can I determine what's input, what's output and how many of them are in the circuit diagram?

Comment: How many inputs of a gates are "driven directly" from the outputs of the gates?

Comment: are these open-collector gates (SN7407) on the left?

Comment: Or notice that XYZ are the gates input's and ABCD are the gate outputs.

Comment: Honestly I only know as much information as I presented, there is nothing more said. I premuse they are open-collector.

Comment: Yup @G36 according to the solution I think that's right; but how can I tell which gates are on the inputs and which gates are on the outputs?

Comment: From the resistor R point of view, the inputs are XYZ and the outputs are ABCD

Comment: @G36 I am wondering: how can I tell if the outputs are open-collector type or not, if it is not explicitly said in the task? Can I somehow "read" it from the above circuit diagram?

Comment: Ther are "normal" output gates (totem-pole output). And your task was to calculate the proper value of a pull-up resistor.  If they were the open-collector gates they would mention it or give the gate number/type.

Comment: Do you have a book that says anything about connecting multiple outputs together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably have been clearer to put the letters right on the gates themselves. "A" refers to the output of the gate just to its left, and the same thing applies to "B", "C" and "D". Similarly, "X" refers to the input of the gate to its right, and so on for "Y" and "Z".